# How to get all contacts from Contact plugin in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using Contact plugin in phonegap by following code

```
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    var options = {
        multiple:true
    }
    options.multiple = true;
    var fields = ["displayName","phoneNumbers"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccessContact, onErrorContact, options);
```

Here, im getting the contacts who are displayName is null.

I dont want this type of filter. I want to get all the contacts from this plugin. How can i change the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter   = "";
options.multiple = true;
```

The Contacts Plugin is poorly documented. 
My notes are here:

http://codesnippets.altervista.org/documentation/phonegap/plugins/navigator.contacts.docs.html

Working App Here:

http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html

Comment: If i give options.filter = "" , It is getting dispalyName=NULL values contacts not all contacts

Comment: My code works on Android 4.x and iOS 8.x with PhoneGap 3.2 via PhoneGapBuild.

Comment: My code works on Android 4.x and iOS 8.x with PhoneGap 3.2 via PhoneGapBuild. Take my code and build, maybe you'll find your problem. It is likely a typo.

Comment: I have tried your code. Both are same. but no use for me

Comment: @Mohaideen, Sorry. All I can tell you is the code works for me on the devices listed on my webpage. I am getting all the contacts. The information shows up at the bottom of the screen. The information shows up as a JSON dump. That is as much as I can tell you. I will take a screenshot and post it, the next change I get.

Comment: @Mohaideen, one of my android tablets which I did not test, is not working. It is a *Samsung GT-P3113 with Android version 4.2.2*. The other Android devices are working 4.0.4 & 4.4.2. I check the device. It has contact entries. So somehow it is failing. I have no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are some contact properties for this plugin, for example you can use id, name, nickname. Here the documentation where you can find it: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html

For example:

```
options.multiple = true;
var fields = ["nickName","phoneNumbers"];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccessContact, onErrorContact, options);
```

And a example with a options filter:

```
options.multiple = true;
var fields = ["nickName","phoneNumbers"];
options.filter   = "Robert";
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccessContact, onErrorContact, options);
```

I hope you find them useful.